# Facebook ad account insights node not returning metadata

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The /2.5/{ad-account-id}/insights?access_token={access_token}&metadata=1 endpoint returns actual data, not metadata with fields.

This is the doc I'm looking at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/. How does one get metadata for this endpoint?